# How to assign taxonomy menu to a link in main menu?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a side menu, based on taxonomy dictionary with the [Taxonomy menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module. But I need to have a duplicate of that menu, that will be a dropdown from one of main menu links. Main menu is manipulated with [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) module.

I can write a jQuery script, that will manipulate with DOM, but it's crazy

How can I achieve this in right Drupal way?

Comment: Hi Alex and welcome to Drupal answers! I think you will find that often there is more than one "right" Drupal way, and our guidelines typically prefers users to stay away from subjective questions like "what's the best module" "the best way" etc. You will anyway find the best answer that fits your scenario once there are some answers and you should accept the best one. Having said that, check out [menu_build_tree](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_build_tree/7) you might be able to programmatically create a new Main Menu item and assign the Taxonomy tree to it